# Ubuntu - Udev is mounting RAID array before system can mount in fstab

Tags: linux, ubuntu, udev

I tried to use the following Udev rule from https://www.axllent.org/docs/view/auto-mounting-usb-storage/

```
KERNEL!="sd[a-z][0-9]", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"  
# Import FS infos  
IMPORT{program}="/sbin/blkid -o udev -p %N"  
# Get a label if present, otherwise specify one  
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}!="", ENV{dir_name}="%E{ID_FS_LABEL}"  
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="", ENV{dir_name}="usbhd-%k"  
# Global mount options  
ACTION=="add", ENV{mount_options}="relatime"  
# Filesystem-specific mount options  
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="vfat|ntfs", ENV{mount_options}="$env{mount_options},utf8,gid=100,umask=002"  
# Mount the device  
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mkdir -p /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/mount -o $env{mount_options} /dev/%k /media/%E{dir_name}"  
# Clean up after removal  
ACTION=="remove", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/bin/umount -l /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/rmdir /media/%E{dir_name}"  
# Exit  
LABEL="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
```

With the intention of of automatically mounting USB drives to our server running Ubuntu, but upon a reboot I found that Udev mounts sda1 (our RAID array) to /media/usbhd-sda1 before fstab can mount it to /root causing the server to stall and boot into initramfs since sda1 is busy/in use.

I have tried to boot into recovery mode using the install disc and remove this rule from Udev and refresh rules, but it hasn't made any difference. How can I remove this rule so I can boot into Linux properly?